# Why is the For loop looping the incremented number multiple times?

Tags: powershell

Alright, so I'm trying to create a script that just renames files within a directory.

Within the Directory there's 2 folders and within each folder there's multiple pictures.

I'm using recurse to go through all of them.

My goal is to rename every single file with the incremented number, but this is not working, instead the script will rename files  with the name number (1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,etc)

Anyone able to help with this issue? Any response is appreciated.

---

What Works:

If I replace what's written inside the script block with:

```
echo $i
```

it'll increment with no problem (1, 2, 3, 4, etc)

this does not work:

```
$targetPath | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + '_' + $I}
```

---

CODE I'M WORKING WITH:

```
cls

$targetPath = Get-ChildItem -File -path C:\Users\Alban\Pictures\Joshua32GBBackUp -Recurse

$numberOfFiles = Get-ChildItem -File -path C:\Users\Alban\Pictures\Joshua32GBBackUp -Recurse | Measure-Object | % {$_.count}



for($i = 1 ; $i -le $numberOfFiles ; $i++ ) {

  $targetPath | Rename-Item -NewName $i -WhatIf

}
```

Comment: `$TargetPath` is likely a _collection_ and you are renaming all of them to the current index number. ///// also, do you really want to name `File.txt` to `1`?

Comment: You'd need something like foreach($file in $targetpath){rename-item}

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you so much for replying so fast! I would Preferably like to rename the files with: " $targetPath | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + '_' + $I} "  and how would you rewrite this script so it could run properly?

Comment: @Clev I'll give a Foreach loop a go and report back

Comment: @Clev so I tried doing a foreach loop and got the same results. I tried the following:    foreach($file in $targetPath) {
 
$count = $count + 1
 
$targetPath | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + "_$count.JPG"} -WhatIf
 
 
}

Comment: @GeorgeAlbanese - you seem to be trying to rename files with the directory name plus a number. is that correct? can you post two original files and the way you want them renamed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the files as part of the for loop too, like this:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i -le $numberOfFiles ; $i++ ) {
   #use indexing to pick the nTh file from the list
  $targetPath[$i] | Rename-Item -NewName $i -WhatIf

}
```

Note that I dropped your initial setting for `$i` down to zero, because PowerShell begins indexes at zero.

But I wouldn't do this in production, many people find the logic of a for loop too hard to understand.  It would be better to iterate through the files directly and rename them that way instead, like so.

```
#Set initial value to zero
$i = 0

ForEach ($file in $targetPath){
    $newName = "$($file.BaseName)_$i$($file.Extension)"
    Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    $i++
}
```

Comment: This really helped me! So I modified your script a bit and got it working to how I want it! Mainly just changed the $file.BaseName to $file.Directory.Name and the path field. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

To have the files still usable after renaming,

- keep the extension and possibly a common prefix.
- As `Rename-Item` accepts piped input no foreach is neccessary
- for easier sorting I recommend leading zeroes for the counter

---

```
$Counter = 0
Get-ChildItem -File -path C:\Users\Alban\Pictures\Joshua32GBBackUp -Recurse|
    Rename-Item -NewName {'File_{0:D3}{1}' -f $Script:Counter++,$_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`